# Mapping XML with JAXB, when the fields are generic, and the actual field names are mapped elsewhere?

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, jaxb

In my java(/spring/hibernate) web app, I am contending with XML like this (I've simplified it down a lot for example purposes - I cannot modify the XML as I'm receiving it from a third party - I only control the client code, and client domain objects - there is no XSD or WSDL to represent this XML either):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Records count="22321">
    <Metadata>
        <FieldDefinitions>
            <FieldDefinition id="4444" name="name" />
            <FieldDefinition id="5555" name="hair_color"  />
            <FieldDefinition id="6666" name="shoe_size" />
            <FieldDefinition id="7777" name="last_comment"/>
            <!-- around 100 more of these --> 
        </FieldDefinitions>
    </Metadata>

    <!-- Several complex object we don't care about here --> 

    <Record contentId="88484848475" >
        <Field id="4444" type="9">
            <Reference id="56765">Joe Bloggs</Reference>
        </Field>

        <Field id="5555" type="4">
            <ListValues>
                <ListValue id="290711" displayName="Red">Red</ListValue>
            </ListValues>
        </Field>

        <Field id="6666" type="4">
            <ListValues>
                <ListValue id="24325" displayName="10">10</ListValue>
            </ListValues>
        </Field>

        <Field id="7777" type="1">
            &lt;P&gt;long form text here with escaped XML here too
            don't need to process or derefernce the xml here, 
            just need to get it as string in my pojo&lt;P&gt;
        </Field>
    </Record>
    <Record><!-- another record obj here with same fields --> </Record>
    <Record><!-- another record obj here with same fields--> </Record>
    <!-- thousands more records in the sameish format --> 
</Records>
```

The XML contains a 'records' element, which contains some metadata, then lots of 'record' elements. Each record element contains lots of 'field' entries.

My goal would be to use JAXB to unmarshall this XML into a large collection of 'record' objects. So I could do something like this:

```
List<Record> unmarhsalledRecords = this.getRecordsFromXML(stringOfXmlShownAbove)
```

where each record would look like this:

```
public class Record {
    private String name;
    private String hairColor;
    private String shoeSize;
    private String lastComment; 
    //lots more fields
    //getters and setters for these fields 
}
```

However, I've never needed to dereference field names in jaxb - is that even possible with jaxb - or do I need to write some messy/hard to maintain code with a stax parser?

None of the examples I can find online touch on anything like this - any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think jaxb supports complex mapping logic like. A couple of options that I can think of.

1. Transform the xml using [freemarker](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/xgui.html) or xslt (I hate xslt) to an xml format that matches your desired model before parsing with jaxb

Eg

```
<Records>
    <Record>
        <Name>Joe Bloggs</Name>
        <HairColour>Red</HairColour>
        ...
    </Record>
</Records>
```

2. Parse the xml as is and write an adapter wrapper in the java layer which adapts from the inbound jaxb objects to your more "user friendly" model. The adapter layer could call into the jaxb objects under the hood so you could later serialize back to xml after changes

Comment: I was thinking parsing as-is would mean generating entirely new POJOs for each record - but a wrapper with sane getters and setters could be a good compromise. Any idea how to parse as is with JAXB, if each of the generic field elements have different formats based on the 'type' attribute?

Comment: There's a tool, included with the jdk, called xjc which can generate the java model from an xsd. There are maven and gradle plugins to generate the model  at build time. If you don't have the xsd you can generate one from the an xml sample using a tool like [this one](https://www.freeformatter.com/xsd-generator.html)